# Dynamically find duplicates in the list

Tags: c#, .net

I have collection of object and I want find duplicate in the collection given some criteria. My current pseudocode below is using `if else`, kind of ugly logic. Trying to find a better approach

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string C {get;set;}
}


public void FindDuplicates(IList<MyClass> list, string[] criteria)
{
    if(criteria.Length == 1)
    {
        if(criteria[0] == "A")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>x.A).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
        
        if(criteria[0] == "B")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>x.B).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
        
        if(criteria[0] == "C")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>x.C).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
    }
    
    if(criteria.Length == 2)
    {
        if(criteria[0] == "A" && criteria[1] == "B")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.A, x.B}).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
        
        if(criteria[0] == "A" && criteria[1] == "C")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.A, x.C}).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
        
        if(criteria[0] == "B" && criteria[1] == "C")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.B, x.C}).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
    }
    
    if(criteria.Length == 3)
    {
        if(criteria[0] == "A" && criteria[1] == "B" && criteria[2]=="C")
        {
           var dups = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.A, x.B, x.C}).Where(g=>g.Count() >1 ).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if this can be done dynamically. A list will have max 500 items.

Comment: Can you accept as criteria something other than the property names ? e.g. `Func<TSource, TKey> func` ? if so, then `return list.GroupBy(func).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);` would suffice. With the usage as: `var dups = list.FindDuplicates(x => new { x.A, x.B });`.

Comment: I am getting criteria from DB. I can change method signature to take function, however the calling method still have to use `if` logic to construct the correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issuing using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`. You can pass group by criteria as `string`. [documentation](https://dynamic-linq.net/basic-query-operators#groupby)

```
   var keySelecter = string.Format("new({0})", string.Join(",", criteria));
                                                                           
   var groups = list.AsQueryable().GroupBy(keySelecter).Select("new(Key, ToList() AS Values, Count() AS Count)");

        foreach (dynamic grp in groups)
        {
            if (grp.Count > 1) // duplicates
            {
                foreach (var val in grp.Values)
                {
                     // do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something:

```
public static IEnumerable<TReturn> FindDuplicates<TList, TReturn>(IEnumerable<TList> list, string propertyName)
{
    return (IEnumerable<TReturn>)list
        .GroupBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x))
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(x => (TReturn)x.Key);
}
```

And sample usage:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
list.Add(new MyClass(){ Text = "A", Flag = true , Number = 10});
list.Add(new MyClass(){ Text = "A", Flag = false , Number = 1});
list.Add(new MyClass(){ Text = "A", Flag = false , Number = 8});
list.Add(new MyClass(){ Text = "B", Flag = true , Number = 10});

var dupText = FindDuplicates<MyClass, string>(list, nameof(MyClass.Text));
var dupFlag = FindDuplicates<MyClass, bool>(list, nameof(MyClass.Flag));
var dupNumber = FindDuplicates<MyClass, int>(list, nameof(MyClass.Number));
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aL6ZCJ)

This should help.